# what datatype is this to save on mysql 1 - 4.9

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, sqldatatypes

I want to save style ratings that ranges from 1 - 4.9 on my mysql database please what datatype should i use? and i keep getting this error when i save it as a decimal(11,0)

**ErrorException in helpers.php line 747:
Method App\Wasamar\Rating::__toString() must return a string value**

MY CODE

```
$allInputs = Input::all();
    $catalogueStyleId = Input::get('catalogueStyleId');
    $userId = Crypt::decrypt( Input::get('user') );
    $rating = Input::get('rating');


    $countUserStyleRating = count( Rating::where('catalogue_style_id',$catalogueStyleId)->where('user_id','=', $userId)->first() );

    if ( $countUserStyleRating == 0 ) {
        # add new rating data

        $rating = new Rating;
        $rating->user_id = $userId;
        $rating->catalogue_style_id = $catalogueStyleId;
        $rating->catalogue_style_rating = $rating;
        $rating->save();

        echo "Your rating has been noted thank you";
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your decimal definition specifies no decimal points. `DECIMAL(11,0)` means you want to store 11 digits left of the decimal point and none after.

You need to define your decimal as `DECIMAL(2,1)` if you want to store 0.1 to 4.9. The 2 means you want to store two total digits, and the 1 means you want 1 of those digits right of the decimal point.

From the documentation:

> The declaration syntax for a **DECIMAL** column is **DECIMAL(M,D)**. The
>   ranges of values for the arguments in MySQL 5.7 are as follows:
>
> **M** is the maximum number of digits (the precision). It has a range of
>   1 to 65.
>
> **D** is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point (the
>   scale). It has a range of 0 to 30 and must be no larger than **M**.

[MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html)