# ErrorException in helpers.php line 747

Tags: laravel-5

I keep getting this error when i call this controller in saving ratings the user choose on each style in the catalogue, this is related to a question i asked earlier on how it save decimal to the table row ([Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38863675/what-datatype-is-this-to-save-on-mysql-1-4-9))

**ErrorException in helpers.php line 747:
Method App\Wasamar\Rating::__toString() must return a string value**

**MY CONTROLLER**

```
public function styleRating(){

    $allInputs = Input::all();
    $catalogueStyleId = Input::get('catalogueStyleId');
    $userId = Crypt::decrypt( Input::get('user') );
    $rating = Input::get('rating'); // value: 0.1 - 4.9


    $countUserStyleRating = count( Rating::where('catalogue_style_id',$catalogueStyleId)->where('user_id','=', $userId)->first() );

    if ( $countUserStyleRating == 0 ) {
        # add new rating data

        $rating = new Rating;
        $rating->user_id = $userId;
        $rating->catalogue_style_id = $catalogueStyleId;
        $rating->catalogue_style_rating = $rating;
        $rating->save();

        echo "Your rating has been noted thank you";
    }else{

        if ( $countUserStyleRating == 1 ) {
            # update rating data

            $UserStyleRating = Rating::where('catalogue_style_id',$catalogueStyleId)->where('user_id','=', $userId)->first();

            $rating = $UserStyleRating;
            $rating->user_id = $userId;
            $rating->catalogue_style_id = $catalogueStyleId;
            $rating->catalogue_style_rating = $rating;
            $rating->save();

            echo "Your rating has been noted thank you";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok well the error tells you what's going on, you aren't returning anything and you need to return something that implements the `__toString()` method.

Comment: @JaredEitnier I don't understand? it is supposed to pass the inputted rating data to database.

Comment: You are only `echo`ing data to browser, you need to `return` something. Just replace your `echo`s with `return`s.

Comment: i have added the return something but the same error occurs, maybe if you look at the paste you may some better insight to the issue. http://pastebin.com/uN8g4tWc

Comment: on which route you are getting this error ?

Comment: can you explain when does this error occurs

Comment: @jaysingkar on this route `Route::post('admin@catalogue@style@rating@processing', array(
      'uses' => 'Admin\AdminAccountController@styleRating',
      'middleware'   => ['auth', 'acl'],
      'is'           => 'admin'
      ));`

Comment: @jaysingkar when i want to rate the styles it sends an ajax post request to update the rating the user chooses.

Comment: I checked your code but couldn't find anything :-(.

Comment: BTW, `$countUserStyleRating = count( Rating::where('catalogue_style_id',$catalogueStyleId)->where('user_id','=', $userId)->first() );` what are you trying to do in this line ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120722/discussion-between-jaysingkar-and-udeme-samuel).